# Why is the Fermi Dirac distribution defined between energy bands?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, fermi-energy

[image]

For a semiconductor charge distribution profile, I read that the only relevant areas for calculating charge concentrations are those coloured in the image (red for holes, blue for electrons), as charge can only occupy the valence (bottom) and conduction (top) bands.  However, if charge carriers do not occupy the band gap, why is the probability distribution even defined here?

Comment: To define the probability distribution in the conduction and valence bands in a self-consistent way, one determines the distribution completely, including the band gap. And, that way you get various other benefits when one gets in to defect levels, quasi-Fermi levels, etc...

Comment: The probability of occupation is the Fermi function multiplied by the density of states, which is zero in the gap.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/Fermi.html